# Apache cordova no me funciona correctamente

Tags: javascript, html, css, cordova

Estoy hace rato ya lidiando con apache cordova, no lo puedo hacer andar ni en consola ni con visual studio.
El problema en si es que no me deja añadir ninguna plataforma, nisiquiera el navegador.
En este ejemplo trato de añadir el browser en mi proyecto y me tira este error.

> Adding browser project... Running command: cmd "/s /c
>   "C:\Users\Emanuel.cordova\lib\npm_cache\cordova-browser\4.1.0\package\bin\create.bat
>   C:\hello\platforms\browser com.example.hello HelloWorld"" Error: cmd:
>   Command failed with exit code ENOENT

Comment: configuraste tus variables de entorno correctamente en windows?

Comment: Si tengo los sdk, el jdk , git.todo referenciado, hasta referencie el node.js tambien y tambien referencie el mismo cordova pero nada.

Comment: Puedes agregar el log del cmd cuando intentas agregar Android?

Comment: no, no me deja agregar nada

Comment: si no tienes configuradas las variables de entorno, te recomiendo revisar [este enlace](http://helibertoarias.com/movil/instalar-apache-cordova-en-windows/)

Comment: Muestra el error cuando intentas agregar Android a eso me referia

Comment: si,si por eso te digo no me deja agregar nada. nisiquiera windows

Answer (score 0):

tal vez quieras probar esto: https://build.phonegap.com/

Básicamente solo tienes que zipear(también admite git) tu projecto html, subirlo a la página y esperar unos segundos a que el apk esté listo.

Por cierto, ENOENT(Error NO ENTry) significa que hay un archivo que no existe, puede ser que: -**C:\Users\Emanuel.cordova\lib\npm_cache\cordova-browser\4.1.0\package\bin\create.bat**  o  **C:\hello\platforms\browser com.example.hello** No existan en tu pc.